# How to pass only 2nd parameter's value while function has three parameters in js?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments, default-value

```
function range(start=0,end,step=1) {
}
console.log(range(10));
```

Here I want 10 as the "end" value. Default values of "start" and "step" are 0 and 1.

Comment: [Default parameters - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Comment: btw, how do you know if you haned over a start value or a step, if you have only two paramters? btw, a default value is take for `undefined` (literally) value.

Comment: In the Problem statement, they told me if just one argument is given then consider it as the "end" value.And take "start=0","step=1".

Comment: What is the purpose to ask somebody to do a codewars task for you? 
https://www.codewars.com/kata/5298961d9ce954d77b0003a6

Comment: I did not ask to solve it,I just asked for specific help ,I did mention what I exactly ask for.

Comment: So the answer is, it's impossible to have default parameter before normal one. You have to do checks inside the function to determine which one is `start` and which one is `end`

Answer (score 0):

```
function range({start=0, end, step=1}) {

}

console.log(range({step: 10}))
```

Comment: I can not pass it as object, It won't pass tests.

Answer (score 0):

A default value is taken for `undefined` (literally) value.

```js
function range(start = 0, end, step = 1) {
    return [start, end, step];
}
console.log(range(undefined, 10));
```

Comment: I have to call it "range(10)" this way, cause that's how the problem has been set.

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to do it

```
function range(start=0,end, step=1) {}
console.log(range(10,null,1)) 

function range({start=0, end, step=1}) {}
console.log(range({}))
console.log(range({start: 10}))
console.log(range({start: 10,step:10}))
```

the second one is easier to custom

Comment: About 2nd solution, This is from codewars so can not pass parameters as object. Cause that's how they set it. It won't pass tests. Same about the first one, cause they will just pass "range(10)" so I have to pass this test.